# How to write Docker file for .sh script

Tags: docker

i have to run one of my adapter services which has spring-boot in it. My mainclass path and third-party libs are included in .sh file. Thirdparty libs contains my server details and core.jar and web.jar details. Now to run my service i have to upon my .sh file, for this how to write docker file to make it as a container.

Answer (score 0):

Create a shell script like test.sh

## !/bin/bash

read IMAGE_NAME

echo  "FROM $IMAGE_NAME" >> Dockerfile

you can see Dockerfile create in your directory according to these example you have to write a dockerfile.

Comment: Use below links to write a dockerfile https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/

Comment: My question was, if i used to run .sh image it will be convert into container or not. Because my .sh file include Mainclass manifest, thirdparty libs, and core.jar and web.jar paths. And how to include .sh file in docker file??

Comment: No run.sh will not convert into container.You will write a script that change it to dockerfile or run a docker file.

Comment: Yes, i know that we have to write docker file for .sh. But i know writing docker file for jar or war, and my question is, how to write dockerfile for .sh. Is it the same process as jar or war?? @raka